# Controller registers, but gets 404 when returning data

Tags: spring, controller, spring-annotations

This is initializer for Spring.  I'm not using any .xml files.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

@Configuration
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{
                WebAppConfig.class,
                SecurityConfig.class,
                DatabaseConfig.class,
                DataSourceGenerator.class,
                QuartzConfig.class,
                QueueConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.addFilter(
                "facilityFilter", new FacilityServletFilter()
        ).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/api/*");

        servletContext.addFilter(
                "hmacFilter", new HmacFilter()
        ).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/api/*");
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is one of my controllers.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/install")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hi", method = RequestMethod.GET,
            consumes = "*/*", produces = "text/html")
    public String sayHello(){
        return "<html> <head> <title>API</title>" +
                "</head>        <body>        <h1>Welcome to the Eric</h1>" +
                "</body>        </html>";
    }

}
```

All my other controllers appear to work properly, but this one returns a 404 error when I try to hit the endpoint.  The code is hit in the debugger when I invoke it via Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@ResponseBody` to your controller method, else spring would try to search for an view with the name `"<html> <head> <title>API</title>..."`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/install")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hi", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "*/*", produces = "text/html")
    @ResponseBody
    public String sayHello(){
        return "<html> <head> <title>API</title>" +
                "</head>        <body>        <h1>Welcome to the Eric</h1>" +
                "</body>        </html>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Raplh you can do that but if you plan to have more of these methods might as well just replace `@Controller` with `@RestController`